# Switch/String in c

Tags: c, string, switch-statement

I am trying to get this function to return a string.

```
char * vergleich(int random) {
    char *erg;
    switch(random) {
        case 1: erg = "Siccor" ; break;
        case 2: erg = "Paper" ; break;
        case 3: erg = "Rock"  ; break;
        case 4: erg = "Lizard" ; break;
        case 5: erg = "Spock" ; break;
        default: break;
            return erg;
    }
}

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));

    int p1 = rand() % 4;
    int p2 = rand() % 4;

    printf("player1 shows %s\n", vergleich(p1));
    printf("\n\tif Player 2 plays %s or %s Player1 wins\n", vergleich(p1+1), vergleich(p1+3));
    if(p2 == p1 + 1 || p2 == p1 +3) {
        printf("player1 wins");
    }else {printf("player2 wins");}
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I think the initialisation of the function is wrong, but I dont really know how to deal with strings, please help.

If I run the program it just crashes if `case > 2`. and the strings are not displayed right.

Comment: `rand() % 4` will result in possible values of 0, 1, 2, and 3.

Comment: Doesn't fix your problem specifically but `p1` and `p2` will never be 4 or 5 adn it could be 0. I think you may want `p1 = rand() % 5 + 1` this will create a random number from 0-4 and then add one to it so now the range is 1-5 which it appears is what you want

Comment: Looks like you have a syntax error, after the `break` in the `default` case.  The `return` is out of place.

Comment: Your compiler wants to yell at you! Enable compiler warnings and pay heed to them!

Comment: yes, thank you. return was the badboy..

Answer (score 1):

The crash happens since the function `vergleich()` can be called with argument `0` (when `p1` is `0`) and `6` when `p1` is `3`. Zero and six are not handled in the switch, so pointer `erg` points to junk.

So, I suggest to enumerate your items starting from `0` to `4`. To avoid overflow during additions you should also use modulo operation `%`, for example `(p1 + 3) % 5`, `(p1 + 1) % 5`.

To generate random from `0` to `4` you can use `rand() % 5;`.